# Swap partition mount error

Tags: boot, swap

Every time Ubuntu startup, a message is displayed :

> Partition is not mounted, continue to wait, press S to skip mounting,
>   or M for manual setup.

```
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=668c2f48-e93f-415d-a0fe-c6f121d5c42a none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/sda1: UUID="03b6f92e-c0de-4574-a4b4-28d21a1db575" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda5: UUID="ae42e7ce-7f23-4a47-abaf-a0764489a0a0" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda6: UUID="75d57d66-08b9-45e7-aab3-640a0ac0adec" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda7: UUID="8c1b0710-1346-4b8c-b8c0-82fb66cd89cd" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda8: UUID="d6259efc-678e-4b0c-91fe-cb7d26f730aa" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda9: UUID="b665a117-e1f7-4d73-9b42-38e959e7c944" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: You have no swap partition.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just formated the partition to linux-swap , but the message still displayed when I restarted my PC, http://postimg.org/image/apok9dfrx/

Comment: Does UUID match the real UUID of the swap partition? Please add `sudo blkid` output.

Comment: /dev/sda1: UUID="03b6f92e-c0de-4574-a4b4-28d21a1db575" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="ae42e7ce-7f23-4a47-abaf-a0764489a0a0" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="75d57d66-08b9-45e7-aab3-640a0ac0adec" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="8c1b0710-1346-4b8c-b8c0-82fb66cd89cd" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="d6259efc-678e-4b0c-91fe-cb7d26f730aa" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="b665a117-e1f7-4d73-9b42-38e959e7c944" TYPE="ext4"

Comment: You see that UUIDs do not match? Replace UUID in `/etc/fstab` as I said in my answer. The correct one is `03b6f92e-c0de-4574-a4b4-28d21a1db575`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add UUID of your swap partition to `/etc/fstab` file.

Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` and add or replace the line regarding swap like this

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx none swap sw 0 0
```

You can see the UUID of your swap partition in gparted if you click properties.

Comment: this is the message http://postimg.org/image/c2t87yw4d/

Comment: Did you add UUID? Please give output of `cat /etc/fstab`. And please post text, not pictures.

Comment: # swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation

#UUID=668c2f48-e93f-415d-a0fe-c6f121d5c42a none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

Comment: Please add output to your question, not comments. Remove the line with `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0` and remove `#` in the beginning of the previous line. Is UUID correct?

Comment: the problem not solved !! I added the output to the question